# JSSOR slider - difference btwn div class="c" and div u="caption"

Tags: slider, captions

I got confused trying to create a hybrid between the 'List Slider' theme (which uses classes of "t" and "c" for title and caption), and the 'Slider-with-caption' example (which uses u="caption").  What's the difference? And how can I style the titles to appear over the slide and the caption alongside the thumbnails?

I surmise that u="caption" is for animating the caption, but I'm still stuck on how to integrate the two approaches. Simply replacing the div class="c" with the div u="c" busts the whole slider!

Answer (score 0):

re: (which uses classes of "t" and "c" for title and caption)
it's not caption, it is custom thumbnail in html format,

```
<div u="thumb">
    ...
</div>
```

caption is another way to play text/image/content animation,
see [slider with caption](http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html)

Comment: but this does not explain why `u` attribute is used. @jssor it's not in HTML spec, right?

Comment: The `u` attribute is custom attribute. You can use `data-u` instead which is  standard html5 custom attribute.

Comment: The `u` attribute indicates the usage of an element, thus jssor slider can determine what's the purpose of the element.

Comment: Okay. `data-u` sounds more appropriate. Anyway, this is an awesome slider! thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Just create a ID or CLASS intiator after.

ex. div u="thumb" id="right" class="hand">